# tig で diff view を開いたとき、一行が長いときの表示

Tags: untagged

一行が長くて表示が隠れてしまっているときに、
どうすれば折り返せるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.tigrc` (あるいは `~/.config/tig/config`) に以下の設定を追加してください。

```
set wrap-lines = yes
```

行の折り返しはデフォルトでは無効化されています。
詳しくはマニュアルを参照してください https://jonas.github.io/tig/doc/tigrc.5.html

余談ですが、折り返しがない状態でも左右矢印キー (`<Left>`, `<Right>`) に割り当てられている
列スクロールを利用すれば隠れている行を見ることができます。